# Reset PK number based on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a `Post` and `Comments` table.

`Post` has many comments, and `Comment` belongs to a post.

I want to have primary keys which start at 1 when I create a comment for a `Post`, so that I can access comments in a REST-ful manner, e.g:

```
/posts/1/comments/1
/posts/1/comments/2
/posts/2/comments/1
/posts/2/comments/2
```

How can I achieve that with Rails 3?
I am using MySQL as a database.

Bonus: I am using the `Sequel` ORM; an approach compatible with Sequel, not only ActiveRecord, would be awesome.

Comment: Does it have to start at `0`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I meant `1` actually, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't use id for this, as id is a primary key here. What you can do is to add an extra field to your database table like `comment_number` and make it unique in the scope of the post:

```
#migration
def change
  add_column :comments, :comment_number, :integer, null: false
  add_index :comments, [:post_id, :comment_number], unique: true
end

#Class
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  validates :post_id, presence: true
  validates :comment_number, uniqueness: { scope: :post_id } 
end
```

Now with this in place you need to ensure this column is populated:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...

  before_create :assign_comment_number

  private

  def assign_comment_number
    self.comment_number = (self.class.max(:comment_number) || 0) + 1
  end 
end
```

Last step is to tell rails to use this column instead of id. To do this you need to override `to_param` method:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  def to_param
    comment_number
  end
end
```

Update:

One more thing, it would be really useful to make this field read-only:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :comment_id
end
```

Also after rethinking having uniqueness validation on `comment_number` makes very little sense having it is assigned after validations are run. Most likely you should just get rid of it and rely on database index.

Even having this validation, there is still a possible condition race. I would probably override save method to handle constraint validation exception with retry a couple of time to ensure this won't break application flow. But this is a topic for another question.

Comment: Nice solution! I had hoped there would be something at the Database-level, but never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Another option without changing models:

```
get 'posts/:id/comments/:comment_id', to: 'posts#get_comment'
```

And in the posts controller:

```
def get_comment
  @comment = post.find(params[:id]).comments[params[:comment_id] -1]
end
```

Asumptions: Comments bookmarks might change if coments deletion is allowed.

Comment: +1 Really nice solution if you prefer dynamic index assignation!

Comment: This might be risky. If there are 5 comments on post then last comment will have path `post/1/comments/5`. WHen one of those comments is removed, it will change to `post/1/comments/4`, while user already bookmarked previous path.

Comment: @BroiSatse I just wanted to mention this race condition. Thanks